# objective-c init UITableViewController with data array?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, uitableview

I have four buttons, which have to push the same uiTableViewController, with different data in every case. I think I need to implement an initializer for my table and pass a NSArray. and then I'll check which button is pushed with the sender property.

Is that ok? How can I implement this initializer? I searched in the doc but I haven't get solution yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your view controller you can initialize tableview by `[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];` and put this initialization in viewdidload method of your view controller,you don't need xib now.
to be specific use

```
    [self.tableView = [UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.96 green:0.96 blue:0.96 alpha:1.000];
    self.tableView.bounces=YES;
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
```

Comment: One more specific question. If I'll use seperated tableView (four tables)for each buttons, this will be a waste and abuse of ressource or it's neglected ?

Comment: you can use single table ,and set its datasource differently ,and yes you can use 4 table because only one table is allocate per button other table are just ignored if u put if case and use it.anyway i prefer to use one and set its datasource according to my use. good luck